# Does the comma in my example sentence add clarity, or should I leave it out?

Tags: meaning-in-context, punctuation, commas, ambiguity

> I quickly realized, homeless people listen to and trust other homeless
> people.

I chose to include the comma to ensure readers understand it was the *'listen to'* and *'trust'* that I realized and not only the homeless people. If I don't use the comma, I'm concerned some readers will misinterpret the sentence to mean, *"I quickly realized there are homeless people who listen to and trust other homeless people."*

I cannot find any information that will answer my question.

Comment: I'd replace the comma with the word "that".

Comment: The comma only confuses.  BoldBen's suggestion is a good one.

Comment: [Reporting Verbs](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/verb-patterns-verb-that-clause)

Comment: Yes @BoldBen solves the riddle, though your two versions and no comma or 'there' all amount to practically the same thing. I could also live with—an em dash or a colon announcing your insight.